# How to load more than one javascript library async in AngularJS sequentially?

Tags: angularjs

In angular, how do I load the url stored in variable "async2Url" script after the url in "asyncurl" loads? Note that the async2Url depends on contents of the response of asyncurl before directives can use it.

I am currently using the following code to load a single script "asyncUrl", how do I make it such that both "asyncUrl" and "async2url" both load (one after the other) before returing the promise?:

```
// Google async initializer needs global function, so we use $window
angular.module('GoogleMapsInitializer')
    .factory('Initializer', function($window, $q){

        // maps loader deferred object
        var mapsDefer = $q.defer();

        // Google's url for async maps initialization accepting callback function
        var asyncUrl = 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?callback=';
        var async2Url = 'https://urltoseconscript/script2.js';

        // async loader
        var asyncLoad = function(asyncUrl, callbackName) {
          var script = document.createElement('script');
          //script.type = 'text/javascript';
          script.src = asyncUrl + callbackName;
          document.body.appendChild(script);
        };

        // callback function - resolving promise after maps successfully loaded
        $window.googleMapsInitialized = function () {
            mapsDefer.resolve();
        };

        // loading google maps
        asyncLoad(asyncUrl, 'googleMapsInitialized');

        return {

            // usage: Initializer.mapsInitialized.then(callback)
            mapsInitialized : mapsDefer.promise
        };
    })
```

Inside the directive, I include:

```
Initializer.mapsInitialized.
    .then(function(){
        map = new google.maps.Map(element, options);
    });
```

If I can retain what I have inside the directive the same and just change the contents of the "GoogleMapsInitializer" module, it would be the best. It would be even better if it could easily support say a 3rd script that depends on the first one (or 2nd one). If not possible to preserve without changes to what I currently have inside the directive code, then what is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about this version

```
angular.module('GoogleMapsInitializer').factory('Initializer', function($window, $q) {

    // Google's url for async maps initialization accepting callback function
    var asyncUrl = 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?callback=';
    var async2Url = 'https://urltoseconscript/script2.js';

    // async loader
    var asyncLoad = function(asyncUrl, callbackName) {

        var deferred = $q.defer();

        var script = document.createElement('script');
        if (callbackName) {
            $window[callbackName] = deferred.resolve;
            asyncUrl += callbackName;
        }
        else {
            script.onload = deferred.resolve;
        }
        script.src = asyncUrl;
        document.body.appendChild(script);

        return deferred.promise;
    };


    // loading google maps
    var mapsPromise = asyncLoad(asyncUrl, 'googleMapsInitialized').then(function() {
        return asyncLoad(async2Url);
    });

    return {
        // usage: Initializer.mapsInitialized.then(callback)
        mapsInitialized: mapsPromise
    };
});
```

Check little demo I set up to test loader.

#### Demo: http://plnkr.co/edit/WYp2kjXWwrAE8xinph15?p=preview